# function which works in javascript but when called in angular it makes an infinite loop

Tags: angular, typescript

I have adapted a function I've found which use d3.js, to draw timeknots. When I test it with javascript and html, it works perfectly (the timeknots are perfectly drawn) , but when I try to call this function in my angular app, the timeknots are well drawn but infinitely. Does anybody know why ?

I work with the same data, the same function.

```
draw(id, events, options){
//Propriétés de la timeline
var cfg = {
  width: 4000,
  height: 80,
  radius: 5,
  lineWidth: 1,
  color: "#999",
  background: "#FFF",
  dateFormat: "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S",
  horizontalLayout: true,
  showLabels: false,
  addNow: false,
  dateDimension: false
};
let points = [];
let index = 0;
let position;
let j = 0;
let prem = true;
let paire = false;

//default configuration overrid
if(options != undefined){
  for(var i in options){
    cfg[i] = options[i];
  }
}

var tip = d3.select(id)
  .append('div')
  .style("opacity", 0)
  .style("position", "absolute")
  .style("font-family", "Helvetica Neue")
  .style("font-weight", "300")
  .style("background","rgba(0,0,0,0.5)")
  .style("color", "white")
  .style("padding", "5px 10px 5px 10px")
  .style("-moz-border-radius", "8px 8px")
  .style("border-radius", "8px 8px");
var svg = d3.select(id).append('svg').attr("width", 
cfg.width).attr("height", cfg.height);


var maxValue = 400;
var minValue = 0;
var margin = (d3.max(events.map(function(d){return Number(d.radius)})) || 
Number(cfg.radius)*1.5+cfg.lineWidth);
var step = (1500-2*+margin)/(maxValue - minValue)*2.5;
var series = [];

var linePrevious = {
  x1 : null,
  x2 : null,
  y1 : null,
  y2 : null
}



//Ici on définit la ligne sur laquelle sont les points
svg.selectAll("line")
  .data(events).enter().append("line")
  .attr("class", "timeline-line")
  .attr("x1", function(d){
  return 0;
  })
  .attr("x2", function(d){
  return 4000   ;
  })
  .attr("y1", function(d){
    return Math.floor(cfg.height/2);
  })
  .attr("y2", function(d){
    return Math.floor(cfg.height/2);
  })
  .style("stroke", function(d){
    return cfg.color
  })
  .style("stroke-width", cfg.lineWidth);
}
```

I expect the function to draw one line but it draws multiple lines.

Comment: How do you call this function in your Angular app?

Comment: in the html file of my component, like this : <td id="arriel1"  style="vertical-align: top;">{{draw('#arriel1',arriel1,{dateDimension:false, color: "teal", labelFormat: "%Y"})}}</td>

Comment: You're calling that function constantly as part of angular lifecycle. Move the function call to your ngOnInit lifecycle hook.

Comment: You should not use functions in bindings. your function will be called on every change detection cycle and angular runs x2 cycles in dev mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you call the function from html it's called every time when Angular detectChanges cycle runs. Thus you get a huge number of function calls.

You should move it inside the component code, not template. I think it should be `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook so the template is ready for manipulations